# updating one attribute fails by validation laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ardent

I have an Ardent (Laravel 4) model with validation rules as below:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'title'      => 'required|alpha_num|min:4',
    'friendly'   => 'required|alpha_num|url'
);
```

When I try this:

```
$page = Page::find($id);
$page->menu=1;
$page->save();
```

It fails, because of the validation rules of other fields. My question is how can I update only one field as above?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well...doesn't seem right. Is it a Laravel bug or intentional?

Answer (score 1):

### Force save without validation in Laravel

If you want to force save your model without validation, simply use the `forceSave()` method instead of `save()`.

```
$model->forceSave()
```

Comment: This seems more like a workaround though? We should be able to validate a single field, the one being updated, while ignoring ones that aren't affected?

Answer (score 0):

Adding "sometimes" worked in my case. Equivalent code for you would be:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'title'      => 'sometimes|required|alpha_num|min:4',
    'friendly'   => 'sometimes|required|alpha_num|url'
);
```

See: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules